# Drawing a circle with cos() sin(), no repeat pixel, no gaps?

Tags: python-2.7, trigonometry

I'm interested in drawing a circle of a vary radius using sin() and cos() functions.

Is there a golden rule to increment the radians so that there isn't multiple plots to the same location and no gaps in the circle drawn on a pixel based display?

```
x = cos(r) * radius
y = sin(r) * radius
r = r + s
```

My guess would be that s is something to do with dividing 2 × PI by the a number derived from the radius?

I'm sure this is either really simple or impossible due to the limitations of floating point calculations.

Thanks for your time

Anthony

Comment: If you know the target resolution, it's better to calculate two values of y for each x: `y = +-sqrt(r*r - x*x)`

Answer (score 0):

The length of arc is simply `s = r * delta_fi` where `r` is the radius of the circle, `fi` is the angle and `delta_fi` is the change of the angle.

The projection of this arc to x-axis is `delta_x = s * sin(fi)` and to y-axis it is `delta_y = s * cos(fi)`

You want such `delta_fi` that either `delta_x` or `delta_y` is 1.

Obviously, the problem is symmetrical and we can solve it for `fi` from -45° to 45° and for `delta y` and then apply the same solution in other quadrants. We have:

`r * delta_fi * cos(fi) = 1`

Hence:

`delta_fi = 1/cos(fi)/r`

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of a circle can indeed be completely defined using the trigonometric functions sine and cosine:

*x = cos(angle)*

*y = sin(angle)*

If the radius is any other value than 1 (which happens to define the unit circle), the underlying principles of trigonometric functions still apply and, therefore, the following equations can be derived:

*x = cos(angle) * radius*

*y = sin(angle) * radius*

To implement this in Python (with the kind help of Numpy) all that is necessary in addition to what we have already defined is a suitable vector (or 1-dimensional array) for the angle, which will be evaluated by the function x and y.

```
import numpy as np

r = 2                                 # An arbitrary value for the radius

angle = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000) # A vector covering all angles from
                                      # 0 to 2*pi (the full circle in radians) 
                                      # with an arbitrary number of 
                                      # elements, 1000 in this example
x = np.cos(angle)*r
y = np.sin(angle)*r
```

On plotting this circle don't forget to adjust the size of the figure to a square, otherwise the circle will be distorted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to how this answer addresses the "no repeat, no gaps" condition(s)?